# How to delete multiple rows of database using ajax and spring mvc

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, java-ee-6

I want to delete multiples rows using `ajax` and `spring mvc` but it always delete just one row.

```
 //code controller 

@RequestMapping(value = "/rmvclientserviceajax", method =  RequestMethod.POST)

@ResponseBody

public void rmvclintServiceajax (HttpServletRequest request, Model model) 
        {
          for(String serviceID: request.getParameterValues("idService"))
            {  Long clientID = (long) Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idClient"));              
              metiersr.deleteClientToService(clientID,(long) Integer.parseInt(serviceID));}            
        }

//code js

 function AjaxPostdelete() {
        if ($('#idService').prop('checked')) {
                   var idService = $('#idService').val();
                   var idClient = $('#idClient').val();
                      $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            url : "/cp/client/rmvclientserviceajax",
                            data : "idClient=" + idClient + "&idService=" + idService,
                                 success : function(response) {
                                   {
                       {
            }      
     }  

// code html   
   <form> 
        <ul class="liste_servch">
              <input type="hidden" id="idClient" value="${client.idPersonne}" />
                  <c:forEach items="${listservclt}" var="servclt">
                      <li>
                        <input id="idService"  type="checkbox"  value="${servclt.idService}" />
                        <c:out value="${servclt.nomService}" />
                      </li>
                  </c:forEach>
        </ul>
             <input type="button" value="supp" onclick="AjaxPostdelete() ">
   </form>
```

Comment: Would you like post your js code please?

Comment: Are you able to hit your controller method with value in serviceID ??
Better you post your JS code and error log.

Comment: @Mippy   i added my code js ,

Comment: @deepesh kumar yes i need use serviceID and my function  work but i can  just delete one row! but me want delete multiple rows in same time.

Comment: Ok, what i understood you are able to delete single row. Right???
change the query and use the 'in' keyword.

Comment: @deepesh kumar don't understood , how i can use 'in' Keyword!

Answer (score 0):

Try following;)

```
function AjaxPostdelete() {
    var idServiceObjs = $('input[id=idService]');
    var idServices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < idServiceObjs.length; i++) {
         if(idServiceObjs[i].prop('checked')) {
             idServices.push(idServiceObjs[i].value);
         }
    }
    var idClient = $('#idClient').val();
    $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url : "/cp/client/rmvclientserviceajax",
         data : {idClient:idClient,idService:idServices},
         success : function(response) {
         }
    }
```

}